# Moment - Get date format section name

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

In order to implement a date input mask, I need to find the literal date section based on a format part.

I've search in the [Moment.js document](https://momentjs.com/docs/) but nothing seems to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's an example of what I would like to do :

```
function getFormatName(format) {
  // [Use some moment.js' method or implement something manually...]
}

getFormatName('YYYY') // Return 'years'
getFormatName('MM') // Return 'months'
getFormatName('DD') // Return 'days'
getFormatName('HH') // Return 'hours'
getFormatName('hh') // Return 'hours'
getFormatName('mm') // Return 'minutes'
getFormatName('ss') // Return 'seconds'
```

I need this method to increment / decrement a specific part of the date, with the `add` / `substract`, which takes a key ('years', 'days', etc)

```
moment().add('years', 1);
```

I though that I could use the shorthands (visible [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)) but some cases would not work without transformations (the days' shorthand is 'd' while the format is provided with capitalized 'D').

Do you think that I could find a solution other than a big `switch/case` ?

```
function getFormatName(format) {
  switch(format[0]) {
    case 'Y':
      return 'years';
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: d returns the day of week i.e it will return  0 to 6 , but D returns the Day of month.

Comment: I think you can try with object {Y: 'years'}. Will be better than switch/case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. And it's consistent with display formatting, since it's using the same internal aliasing:

```
function getFormatName(format) {
    const unit = moment.normalizeUnits(format[0])
    return unit ? unit + 's' : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice one, didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a function that moment has for this, but it's fairly simple with an object literal

```js
getFormatName('YYYY') // Return 'years'
getFormatName('MM') // Return 'months'
getFormatName('DD') // Return 'days'
getFormatName('HH') // Return 'hours'
getFormatName('hh') // Return 'hours'
getFormatName('mm') // Return 'minutes'
getFormatName('ss') // Return 'seconds'

function getFormatName(s, plural = true) {
  let trans = {
    YYYY: 'year',
    MM: 'month',
    DD: 'day',
    HH: 'hour',
    hh: 'hour',
    mm: 'minute',
    ss: 'second'
  };
  if (! trans[s]) throw new Error('no translation found');
  return trans[s] + (plural ? 's' : '');
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if the library had a function to do the same thing, but implements it isn't a big deal. Thanks for the help.